# VUE why action fires many times

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm creating function which send information to webserver about mouse position, when mouse button is down (click).
Generaly it works fine, but it fires too many times.
After page refresh:
first click -> method fires 1 time
second click -> methos fires 2 times
third click -> method fires 3 times
and so on...

The HTML code is:

```
      <div id="draw-image-test">
        <canvas
          id="canvasId"
          ref="canRef"
          @mousedown="clickMe"
        />
      </div>
```

and method :

```
clickMe() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId')
  canvas.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left - canvas.clientLeft
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top - canvas.clientTop
    this.xpos = Math.round(x)
    this.ypos = Math.round(y)
    this.click = {
      cmd: 'rightClick',
      x: Math.round(x),
      y: Math.round(y),
    }
    this.sendMessage(this.click)
  })
},
```

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Common problem. You wrote `this.click` inside `addEventListener('click')`. So every time you click, it adds another click listener.

Comment: But this.click is my variable - JSON. Everytime i click, x and y is different, so i create new JSON with current cursor position

Comment: Change your variable name from click to something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mouseup() in a mousedown() called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215771/mouseup-in-a-mousedown-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everytime you click on your canvas, you add an event listener to it.

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', event => { [...]
```

this is your issue. You just need to do the logic you need in the clickMe, not add an other event listener to your canvas. The @mousedown event will send the event parameter with the wanted coordinates :

```
clickMe(event) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId')
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left - canvas.clientLeft
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top - canvas.clientTop
  this.xpos = Math.round(x)
  this.ypos = Math.round(y)
  this.click = {
    cmd: 'rightClick',
    x: Math.round(x),
    y: Math.round(y),
  }
  this.sendMessage(this.click)
},
```